# wordpress redirect after password reset

Tags: password, wp-login-form, reset

I would like to able to redirect to `get_bloginfo('url');` after reseting password.

But I cannot for life of me find any simple answer or function to do this.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thank
Josh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Im hooking into `login_headerurl`. Maybe there is a better hook for this but it works, Put this in your functions.php:

```
function wpse_lost_password_redirect() {

    // Check if have submitted 
    $confirm = ( isset($_GET['checkemail'] ) ? $_GET['checkemail'] : '' );

    if( $confirm ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('login_headerurl', 'wpse_lost_password_redirect');
```

What it does, it runs on `login_headerurl` and checks for the GET parameter "checkedmail" which you get after you submitted a valid username or email. Then i redirect by using the awsome function [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to the [home_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url).

**UPDATE after comment**

If you want to redirect the user after submitted a new password you only need to use the hook [password_reset](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/password_reset) here is an example:

```
function wpse_lost_password_redirect() {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
    exit;
}
add_action('after_password_reset', 'wpse_lost_password_redirect');
```

Comment: Hi Pontus, thank you very much for your answer, this will come use for another time i'm sure. But I'm in fact after the re-direct after the new passord itself has been reset, not after the email/user submission. See this screenshot of form that I need it the redirect to work on... http://i.imgur.com/x2IUQ0c.jpg - Thanks

Comment: Aaah i see, thats actually easier than the function before. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awgh dude, these are both awesome!! Thanks for sharing with us, it worked at treat! Nice one.

Comment: I just used your first answer for something else, told you it would come in handy. Thank you again.

Comment: Beware that using `password_reset` action is performed **before** actual password resetting is done. Documentation says `Fires before the user's password is reset.`

Comment: The second version does not work correctly because the password will not actually be changed. You must remove the `exit` because this action is performed *before* the password is reset.

Comment: after_password_reset 

Answer (score 12):

The "correct" answer doesn't work here because the action 'password_reset' fires *before* the password is reset.

I modified the first answer, before the update, to work.

```
function wpse_lost_password_redirect() {

    // Check if have submitted
    $confirm = ( isset($_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == resetpass );

    if( $confirm ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('login_headerurl', 'wpse_lost_password_redirect');
```

Edit: Didn't have enough rep to comment so I'm posting this as a new answer.

Comment: This should be posted as an answer. Good job.

Comment: Great solution - working on MS also.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how the "UPDATE after comment" answer works.

The documentation for the 'password_reset' hook says "Fires before the user's password is reset.".
If you redirect, then exit the password won't get changed.

Since I had a similar need I developed my solution to the problem.
We still respond to the "password_reset" hook but instead of performing the redirect immediately we add a hook for the "login_url" filter.
And it's in this filter that we add the redirections to the home page after the user has logged in.

```
 add_action( "password_reset", "rngs_password_reset", 10, 2 );

/**
 * Implement "password_reset" for RNGS
 *
 * After a password reset has been performed we want the Log in link to redirect the user to the home url.
 * When we see this action being run we know that we should be filtering "login_url" to add the redirect the home page.
 * We don't filter "login_url" any other time. 
 *
 * @param WP_User $user - the user object
 * @param string $new_pass - the new password
 *  
 */
function rngs_password_reset( $user, $new_pass ) {
  add_filter( "login_url", "rngs_login_url", 10, 2 );
}

/**
 *  Implement "login_url" filter for RNGS
 *
 * Redirect the user to the home page after logging in
 *
 * @TODO - make this an option field that controls where the logged in user goes
 * @TODO - dependent upon role?
 * 
 * @param string $login_url - the original login_url which is not expected to include "redirect_to" or "reauth"
 * @param string $redirect - expected to be null/blank
 */
function rngs_login_url( $login_url, $redirect ) {
  $home_redirect = home_url();
  $login_url = add_query_arg('redirect_to', urlencode( $home_redirect ), $login_url);
  return( $login_url );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something in the question, but is anything wrong with using the `lostpassword_redirect` filter?

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );

function my_redirect_home( $lostpassword_redirect ) {
    return home_url();
}
```

More here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_redirect

Comment: What you are missing here, `lostpassword_redirect` is the filter for a URL where the user will go after he hits `Forgot Password` button. Then he'll actually reset his password, and when the new password is set, the OP needs a filter/action hook (which is probably `after_password_reset`)

Answer (score -1):

Rediret to is a wordpress feature you don't need to create a plugin for it, just add &redirect_to= the url and it will work.
Example:

```
echo '<a href="'home_url().'/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&amp;redirect_to='.get_bloginfo('url').'?sli=lost" rel="nofollow" title="Forgot Password">'Forgot Password'</a>';
```

Comment: Answers should be more than a code snippet. Please file an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/198724/edit) and explain why this would work.